# Create a project status report in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I’m trying to create a project status report (for a "waterfall view" on an agile software project) in Azure DevOps that is based on a list of Epics and the corresponding Features beneath them. The report should contain information about the overall effort, the current progress (completed features) in % and a planned vs. actual progress comparison to see delays. Best would be to also have the information in a gant chart which is displaying all the information mentioned above.
I already tried various extensions for Azure DevOps but I always failed to implement the planned vs. actual progress

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this, especially with the target vs. actual comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can fully meet your requireemnts. (Generate the report to show the actual progress(overall effort, progress and so on) and the target progress)

In Azure DevOps Service built-in feature, the [Rollup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops) feature in DevOps. Rollup provides summed values of select fields for all child work items of a parent. But the system doesn't support rollup of the Effort,Completed Progress across product backlogs and portfolio backlogs.

It also supports using [Query Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops#other-tools-that-support-rollup) obtain rollup of additional data fields in Azure DevOps work tracking data.

These features have limitations and can not fully meet your needs. As far as I know, the existing extension mainly displays the current progress, and it cannot achieve the comparison function.

You can consider using  [PowerBI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops) or [Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops#microsoft-excel-and-rollup-of-work-tracking-data) to collect the data of the work item query. Then you can perform customized processing on the data and generate reports. For example: [Rollup child work item values to parent sample report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi)

I can fully understand your requirement.You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.